# SharePoint 2013 Javascript is not working in IE 9

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to access sharepoint 2013 list data. Below is the code. This code perfectly works in Chrome. However, when it doesnt work in IE 9. The strange thing is, no errors are logged in console. Also once i press f12 in IE, my code starts working.

```
function retrieveListItems() {

  var siteurl = ; // a url is here
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ResourceAllocator');
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>' + 1 + '</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>');

  this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

  clientContext.load(collListItem);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededs), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFaileds));


}
function onQuerySucceededs(sender, args) {

  var allResourceNAme = [];
  var listItemInfo = '';
  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    //process the data
  }
```

Please help me with the same.

Comment: If pressing f12 works, then you may have something like `console.log` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing F12 brings up the IE console window.  If your Javascript doesn't work when the console isn't open, likely you have `console.log` somewhere in your code.  If the console isn't open in IE, Javascript fails because console isn't defined.  You can add this to your JavaScript to ensure that it never fails due to this "bug"

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
  this.console = {log: function() {}};
}
```

Comment: Hi Robbert, Thanks for the reply. I was struggling with this issue for a week now... thanks a lot